# Odata request is giving error in outlook - crm 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, odata, crm

Below is the code i have used to get Account record values. This is working fine in ie but when i call the same in outlook 2010, its giving error.

```
var guid = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_guid').getValue();
```

I have stored guid of account record in field `new_guid`.

```
http://server:port/organisation/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet(guid'" + guid + "')
```

I'm not able to upload the snapshot of error, since i'm a new user. The error says,

`OData Select Failed:
http://server:port/organisation/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet(guid'{34970124-8C34-E211-9279-005056C00008}')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem. I need to use

`Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl()+"/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet(guid'" + guid.replace("{","").replace("}","") + "')";`

I was hard coding server url , which will not work in outlook but it was working fine in ie.